# How to search and Replace xml file definition in c#

Tags: c#

I need to open an xml file and replace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" href="diwa_klein.xsl"?>
```

My current code is a simple case of

```
File.WriteAllText(@copiedfile, File.ReadAllText(@copiedfile).Replace(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso - 8859 - 15""?> ", @" <?xml version = ""1.0"" ?><? xml - stylesheet type = ""text / xsl"" href = ""diwa_klein.xsl"" ?> "));
```

This way seems to get ignored

Comment: Why do you want to change the encoding? Is the encoding wrong?

Comment: Changing the `encoding` value won't change the file's encoding. If the file contains characters outside the US-ASCII range XML parsers may choke or worse, mangle the non-ASCII characters as they try to parse the file using the *wrong* encoding

Comment: This replacement would only work if the file contained only characters in the US-ASCII range, ie English letters, numbers,space and the few punctuation marks and symbols in that range. In that case UTF8 is indistinguishable from ASCII

Comment: `avoid using the escaped characters` what escaped characters?? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X, think that Y is the solution and when that fails ask about Y, not X. In this case I suspect the original XML is just fine. It may contain *XML encoded text*, though, not escaped characters. That's perfectly fine. All XML parsers would recognize them. It's only *humans* that would find it hard to read the encoded characters

Comment: Some characters like `<` and `>` simply *can't* appear inside an XML element and need to be XML encoded to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, no matter the content's codepage. This can't be avoided. Non-English text like `Γ` would need encoding if the file was saved using a non-Unicode encoding, in this case to `&Gamma;΄. With UTF8 no encoding is needed. Again, this is only needed to make it easy for *humans* to read the XML file.

Comment: Firstly the encoding needs to be in utf-8 and secondly I need to add the xsl stylesheet to the header

Comment: @RobertBuckley that comment doesn't explain anything. What you try won't convert the encoding either

Comment: @RobertBuckley To perform this conversion you'd have to *load* the XML file with an XML parser/serializer and write it back out using UTF8. Simply changing the file's encoding won't replace the encoded characters. `&Gamma;` would remain `&Gamma;`.

Comment: Well....I need to change the text from "iso - 8859 - 15" to "uft-8" otherwise the browser doesnt parse the contents correctly